# extract data from an xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I know this has been asked before, and I have tried a few of the suggestions, but I am not getting the information from the XML file.  I need to get the number of sellers (OfferListingCount condition="Any")from an xml file.  Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="0312479743" status="Success">
<Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
<Identifiers>
  <MarketplaceASIN>
    <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
    <ASIN>0312479743</ASIN>
  </MarketplaceASIN>
</Identifiers>
<CompetitivePricing>
  <CompetitivePrices>
    <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="false" condition="Used" subcondition="Good">
      <CompetitivePriceId>2</CompetitivePriceId>
      <Price>
        <LandedPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>36.23</Amount>
        </LandedPrice>
        <ListingPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>36.23</Amount>
        </ListingPrice>
        <Shipping>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        </Shipping>
      </Price>
    </CompetitivePrice>
  </CompetitivePrices>
  <NumberOfOfferListings>
    <OfferListingCount condition="Any">34</OfferListingCount>
    <OfferListingCount condition="Used">29</OfferListingCount>
    <OfferListingCount condition="New">5</OfferListingCount>
  </NumberOfOfferListings>
```

Here is my UPDATED code for Php:

```
    $priceComp_xml = amazonCompPrice_xml($asin);
$compPricing = $priceComp_xml->xpath('/OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]');
```

$priceComp_xml returns the information from the xml file, and I am trying to use the next line to get the information I need.  When I run the code, get an empty array.
How do I get this information?

Comment: What is this `amazonCompPrice_xml` function?  What does it take as parameters and what does it return?

Comment: amazonCompPrice_aml takes the ASIN value and returns (hopefully) the competitions pricing (the XML listed above).  From that I need to get the $compPricing = $priceComp_xml ->xpath("//GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult/Product/NumberOfOfferListings/OfferListingCount[@condition='Any']");

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

        $output = array();
        foreach ($xml as $row => $item_data)
        {
            // Attributes
            $attributes =  $item_data->attributes();
```

Load it up, get the attributes.

Comment: I can get the file loaded, I am just having trouble getting the information from <OfferListingCount condition="Any">34</OfferListingCount> where it has condition="Any".

Comment: ya, that's what attributes() checks